# what is the connotation of newsie?

Tags: meaning, connotation

I would like to use it in my blog. It is formal enough without any bad connotation?

"nouninformal•US
plural noun: newsies; noun: newsie

```
a reporter.
    a person who sells or delivers newspapers."
```

Comment: Newsie ≏≏ Nosy. Sounds the same.

Comment: It’s so old-fashioned—a word from the days when cities had many newpapers.

Comment: Watch the movie. Christian Bale sings.

Comment: As per the movie, I'd associate it with kids. I'm not American, so it's my only exposure to newsies. (There's a Christian rock band called Newsboys, which is something else to consider.)

Comment: @banuyayi - I (UK) have never heard the word 'newsie' but I wouldn't pronounce it like 'nosy'.

Comment: It sounds the same, if you make your tongue a little lumpy (big around the middle) :)

Comment: @banuyayi - The two do not sound the same.  Can you provide us with the IPA of how you think they sound?  One has the *boot* vowel /u:/, the other the *home* /əʊ/ vowel (dipthong really).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that word was very "Popular" around 1900-1940 , peaking at around 1920 & declining till 1990 when it again got picked up in usage.

> [newsie](https://www.etymonline.com/word/newsie)
> 1875, short for newsboy
>
> newsboy :
> "boy who hawks newspapers on the street or delivers them to houses"

Somewhere in-between , the meaning has changed.

> [newsie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/newsie)
> a person who works in the news industry
>
> including Printers , Publishers & reporters

Here is the usage trend :

> [image: newsie]

Now, the old usage is connected to uneducated boys (& girls) who would speak with illiterate accents :

> [Newsie Accent](https://youtu.be/hHXQZzawqok)

The new meaning may not have this negative connotation, but it might offend those who are not aware of the new meaning (such folks might be rare)

More-over , the new meaning might have the negative connotation that newsies talk too much or are gossipy or are too unemotional or are too pushy in getting answers to report , again offending some other folks.

In the comments, we can see that there is some association between newsie & nosy & small kids. This again endorses the view that this word might be offendable to some folks.

Here is a [Derogatory Statement](https://www.wordsense.eu/newsie/) which give the Public Perception.

There is a new homonym :

> [newsy](https://www.wordsense.eu/newsy/)
>
> Containing lots of news; informative.
> Chatty, gossipy.

Comment: what tool you to get that data/ graph?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=newsie%2CNewsie%2CNEWSIE&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=6

Comment: The tool which I used ( google ngram ) looks at words ( not meanings ) @user95432